# Can DatePart be executed with aggregate functions?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I wrote the following query in Access 2010 that's spitting back an error message:

`SELECT DatePart("ww",Date,2,1) AS WeekNumber, Metric, Sum(MetricValue) AS WeeklyMetricValue
FROM qryActual
GROUP BY Metric, WeekNumber;`

This is the error message:

`You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'DatePart("ww",Date,2,1)' as part of an aggregate function.`

Is there a really simple error that I'm missing or does DatePart need to be executed in a separate query before it can be included in a `GROUP BY`?

Let me know if you need additional details.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it can. The only problem is that you are grouping by the column alias, you need to group by the expression itself, i.e. in the `GROUP BY` replace `WeekNumber` with `DatePart("ww",Date,2,1)`:

```
SELECT  DATEPART("ww",Date,2,1) AS WeekNumber, 
        Metric, 
        SUM(MetricValue) AS WeeklyMetricValue 
FROM    qryActual 
GROUP BY Metric, DATEPART("ww",Date,2,1);
```

---

To elaborate a bit further based on the comment, this is the order in which the parts of the query are executed:

- FROM clause
- WHERE clause
- GROUP BY clause
- HAVING clause
- SELECT clause
- ORDER BY clause

As you can see `SELECT` is very near the bottom, so when the `GROUP BY` is executed the alias does not yet exist, so the only place you can reference column aliases is in the `ORDER BY` clause. (There are DBMS that allow it in other places, e.g. MySQL, but these are the exceptions, not the rule).

Comment: So I hopefully don't make this mistake again...are Aliases defined in the Select statement forbidden in the Group By statement? Or is it only the case when certain types of functions are applied?

Comment: I have expanded on the answer to explain why you can't refer to the aliases in the `GROUP BY`, this is the case for all aliases, not just those with certain functions.

Comment: Fantastic @GarethD! If only I could give you more than one upvote!